# Visual Studio 2019 - Incompatible The application which this project type is based on was not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

After installing Visual Studio 2019 (previously I had 2017), some Web projects appear as

"**Incompatible**"

> The application which this project type is based on was not found.

It still works on 2017 but I haven been able to figure out why I am getting this error.

**Project type:**

```
Web Site    {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}
```

If I launch the VS Installer and install or uninstall any component and then open VS 2019 and my solution it loads fine WebSite and I can run it. If I close it and reopen it a 2nd time it becomes incompatible again.

Does anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue.. It has to do with the .user files.

In order to resolve the problem:

- I searched for all the files in the project directory with extension *.user
- and I removed them all
- last I reloaded the projects

Comment: Too bad, I don't have any single *.user file anywhere in the project as I am experiencing this issue with a newly checked-out solution. ;)

Comment: Hardly, `dir /s/b MyProject\*.user` has no result while it has with other projects. As I've said, it's a newly checked-out solution without any modifications. It's just one of these problems that has various reasons. ;)

Comment: Thanks!!!  I did a `find -name *.user` at the top of my repo, deleted each *.user file, restarted VS2019 and I'm up and running.   The problem this fixed for me was "error  : The application for the project is not installed" for every project (27!) in the solution.  When I tried to reload I got the error "The operation could not be completed.  No such interface supported."

Comment: Not sure how or why I have bit different extension names, but deleting *.rsuser files also helped me with this.

Answer (score 4):

I tried repairing Visual Studio 2019 Community but it didn't work.

A workaround is to remove the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element from the .csproj. It won't look like a "Unit Test project" in Solution Explorer any more, but at least now I can open it. And the tests are still discoverable.

As described in [this answer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unit-test-project-ms-test-not-supported-after-late/858160#T-N878630).

Comment: I had an old solution written in Visual Studio 2015 and was trying to migrate to 2019 and I was getting the same error. I tried all of the above but this one worked for me. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was a wrong version number in project config (.dtproj).
I find this out, while comparing an old file with a new project file from VS2019

Old one:

`<ProductVersion>15.0.2000.132</ProductVersion>`

New one:

`<ProductVersion>15.0.2000.128</ProductVersion>`

The solution:

Changed the version Number in old config file from 132 to 128 and it works.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't really my solution. I've tested it a second time and it didn't work.
The solution ist more simple:
Just reload the project in the 'Solution Explorer'.
Could it be easier?

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem occurred when updating VS2019 from 16.4.5 to 16.4.6.

Solution: Use the VS installer to repair the installation, as describe in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/858160/unit-test-project-ms-test-not-supported-after-late.html).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

Make sure the "Developer Analytics Tools" extension is enabled.

Longer story

Don't be this know-it-all who thinks that doesn't need "Developer Analytics Tools" enabled if you want to use a "Unit Test" project at the same time. Just as I was. Keep it enabled.

Also, consider voting to reconsider a related problem at the Developer Community:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/904418/unit-test-projects-needs-migration-message.html

Kudos to Alexey Lotysh for providing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because a ModelingProject diagrams was involved, trying to import an earlier VS2017 project in a VS2019 environment and it displayed to me all the errors for missing project application, after reading about [live dependancy validation, and that UML designers removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/what-s-new-for-design-in-visual-studio?utm_source=getvssdk&utm_medium=referral&view=vs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) and installing [map dependencies with code maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2017), I updated the ModelingProject and it correclty displayed all solution elements, built and started properly.

Reference images
[image: ModelingProject]
[image: Installation]

Answer (score 1):

In my case I went to "Manage extensions", selected "Installed" and I found out that Microsoft Reporting Service Projects" had been "disabled" (I don't know why/how).

I just pushed the "enable" button, closed and restarted VS2019 and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought to share my solution. Had a similar issue, for one of the solutions projects will just not load. The same error as in the question.

Deleting *.user files did not help, but deleting .vs directory located in the solution directory, and reopening the solution afterwards resolved it for me.

Note thought that .vs is a hidden directory, so you might need to enable viewing them in the Windows Explorer.